# How to convert a drawing in 1cm=1ft to 1 inch=20ft

Tags: adobe-illustrator, scale

I want to convert a drawing done in 1cm=1ft scale to 1 inch=20ft in Adobe Illustrator. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1cm : 1ft = 1 : 30.48

1inch : 20ft = 1 : (20*12) = 1 : 240

30.48 / 240 = 0.127

Scale your drawing by a factor of 0.127:

1. Select your drawing;
2. Choose the Scale tool;
3. <kbd>Alt / Option</kbd>-<kbd>click</kbd> anywhere on your workspace;
4. Enter '12.7%' into the 'Uniform' field in the dialogue that pops up;
5. Press <kbd>Ok</kbd>.